# Reading from AWS S3 is not returning response

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS S3 and I am trying to read a csv from an S3 folder. For which I have the below logic.

```
var prefixList = [];

async function readConfig() {
  const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();
  const csv = require("csv-parser");
  const bucket = "my-bucket";
  const objectkey = "/my/folder/path/filename.csv";
  const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: objectkey };

  const configFile = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();

  configFile.pipe(csv()).on("data", (data) => {
    prefixList.push(data["PREFIX"]);
  });

  logger.info("PrefixList: " + prefixList);
}
```

I am trying to print the list and it prints an empty list. The list is not getting appended by the elements from the csv file.

I have confirmed that the file is there in the bucket/folder path I have mentioned. And also, the header PREFIX is present in the csv file. But still something is preventing the push to the list.

Am I missing something here? Please help

**EDIT**:

*Contents in the S3 file*:

```
--------
PREFIX
--------
MR
MRS
MISS
MS
DR
REV
PROF
SIR
--------
```

Comment: Is your key public? Do you need authentication?

Comment: My bucket shows "Bucket and objects not public"

Comment: My keys are not public I guess

Comment: Then you will need authentication, did you configure your credentials somewhere in your code?

Comment: No Julien I have not. Do you have any article to guide me through?

Comment: Please have a look at this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html

Comment: Okay, now I understand. I have already configured the access key and secret key credentials in `~/.aws/credentials` folder.

Comment: This issue is still occuring

Comment: Do you have only the `default` profile in you aws config or credential file?

Comment: I have the IAM role credentials updated in the credential file. Which will be manually updated every hour using gimme-aws-creds. Not a default profile.

Comment: Can you add the content of the file to your question making sure to replace any sensitive information with placeholders.

Comment: While `/my/folder/path/filename.csv` may technically be valid, it's not what you would use for an S3 object key. The key would be `my/folder/path/filename.csv`, without the leading slash.

Comment: @JulienB. Have updated my question with the contents of the file.

Comment: @jarmod Tried doing that and it throws Access Denied issue.

Comment: @Mike I meant the credentials file